# Do questions have an identification number?

Tags: support

I'm fairly new to Stack Exchange. I'd like to know if questions posted on these sites have a unique ID to identify them by. When I click on any question and look at the link, I usually see a number like:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/######/question-title

And typing in just https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/###### opens that question. Is that number unique to each question on each site? If yes, is there a way to find that number out without looking at the link?

Comment: as i know, the id is a timestamp of yout question

Comment: @gagantous it is not a timestamp but just a incrementing number that started at 1. See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298852/158100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the question number, yes.

Each question and answer has a "share" link underneath that you can click on to get a permalink to that question, and that will have the question/answer number in it, does that do what you need?

For example, for this question:

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302613/134374
```

where 302613 is the question number and 134374 is my user number.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!